# R tikzdevice: How to use sans serif font

Tags: r, fonts, latex, tikz, tikzdevice

I'm using `ggplot` in `R` to create plots, `tikzdevice` to save them and then `latex` to compile them in a larger document.

when I create a very simple plot, e.g.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(tikzDevice)

tikz("test.tikz", height = 4, width = 4)
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(1:3), y = c(1:3)), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
geom_point() +
theme(text = element_text(family = "sans", face = "bold"))
dev.off()
```

While I can change the size and the font face using the `element_text` options in `theme`, changing the font family doesn't work. I.e. the exported `tikz` does not contain the sans-serif command.

How can I export the graphic using sans-serif font for text (and particularly the axis labels)?

Answer (score 0):

`tikz()` will output latex code. The fonts will be the ones specified in this latex document (which is great because that results in a consistent look).

Creating a standalone figure with sans-serif font that you can then render via `pdflatex test.tikz` can be achieved like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(tikzDevice)
options(tikzLatexPackages = 
      c(getOption("tikzLatexPackages"), 
        "\\renewcommand{\\familydefault}{\\sfdefault}\n")
      )

tikz("test.tikz", height = 4, width = 4, standAlone = TRUE)
   ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(1:3), y = c(1:3)), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
   geom_point()
dev.off()
```

We pass in additional text that is written to the preamble via `options`. We need to add new options to the default options and not overwrite them, which is why we concatenate with `getOption("tikzLatexPackages")`. Also note that you have to escape `\`in the R strings.

The second important part is to set `standAlone = TRUE` if we want to render the figure on its own and not make it part of a larger document.

How to set fonts in a latex document I still find somewhat mysterious. My solution builds on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877597/how-do-you-change-the-document-font-in-latex). But you could pass in other latex commands via `options` to set fonts in a different way.